# .doIfEquals not working with gatling version 3.7.6

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling, maven-gatling-plugin

I have been using the gatling version 3.6.1 in my application for the performance testing. Recently I upgraded the version to 3.7.6 and observed that all the conditional statements were not working.
The below doIfEquals condition is not evaluating to true even if the value of index variable, stored in session is 1. On reverting it to previous version, I am not running into this issue.

```
.doIfEquals("${index}", 1) {
//logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Already answered on Gatling community forum](https://community.gatling.io/t/doifequals-not-working-with-gatling-version-3-7-6/6983/2) where this question was also posted: known bug, already fixed several releases ago.

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading the Gatling version to 3.8.2 helped.